# Resolving broken source in Maven central repository

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I need two dependencies from the same organization, but it seems the link to their source is broken.

First: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.moxieapps.gwt/uploader

Second: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.moxieapps.gwt/highcharts

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.moxieapps.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>uploader</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.moxieapps.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>highcharts</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ctap-web: Could not resolve dependencies 
for project com.test:test-web:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could 
not be resolved: org.moxieapps.gwt:uploader:jar:1.1.0, 
org.moxieapps.gwt:highcharts:jar:1.7.0: Could not find artifact 
org.moxieapps.gwt:uploader:jar:1.1.0 in central 
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read 
the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I've downloaded the source from Sourceforge and placed it in `.m2/repository/org/moxieapps/gwt/` but Maven still tries to download it from the central repo.

Comment: review this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286808/add-local-repository-to-maven-settings-xml

Comment: @sc0der Thanks, but I'm still confused. I downloaded the jars directly into the default location `.m2/repository/...` so I shouldn't need to point to anything further?

Comment: you can add the `repositories` that maven lookup local maven then maven central, something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jar `org.moxieapps.gwt:uploader:jar:1.1.0` is *not* in MavenCentral, which you can see here:

https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.moxieapps.gwt%20AND%20a:uploader

Note that `mvnrepository` (the links you provided) have nothing to do with MavenCentral.

Comment: Thank you so much! That explains a lot. So I should still be able to add the jars I've downloaded from SourceForge to my Maven pom as long as I configure the pom to find it properly?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot follow you. What do jars from SourceForge have to do with MavenCentral?

Comment: I am trying to get a large, established project running but it won't compile due to these last two dependencies (both from Moxieapps). It seems this project's source code hasn't been updated in a few years, and perhaps these dependencies have since been removed from MavenCentral(?). So I found the jars elsewhere (SourceForge) and downloaded them but they are not being recognized by the pom.xml. I don't use Java often and have always struggled with Maven so the solution may very well be simple and I am just being dense.

Comment: You can install the jars with `mvn install:install-file` into your local repository.

Comment: BRILLIANT! Thank you so much!